# ActiveModelSerializers gem: how to pass parameter to serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, active-model-serializers

I'm updating the gem [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) from version 0.9.5 to 0.10.1. For version 0.9.5 the code below worked.

Controller:

```
def create
  ...
  render json: @dia, app_rights: app_rights(@dia)
end
```

Serializer:

```
class Api::V1::SerializerWithSessionMetadata < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :app_rights
  def app_rights
    serialization_options[:app_rights]
  end
end
```

The method `serialization_options` has been deprecated in version 0.10.1.

- [Here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/howto/passing_arbitrary_options.md) it is suggested to use `instance_options` instead.
- [Here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/599) it is suggested to use `options`: "instance_options is only available in the master branch, not in the current RC. In the current RC, you have to use options instead".
- There are also suggestions for `@options` and `@instance_options`.

I have tried replacing `serialization_options` with all the above options. However, in all cases, after updating the gem, the json produced does not include `app_rights`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what rails and ruby version are you using ? according to changelog support for Rails 4.0 and ruby 2.0.0 is dropped

Comment: Using the latest versions: ruby 2.3.1 and rails 4.2.6

Comment: hmmm interesting that they say 0.10.x isn't backwards compatible with 0.9 or 0.8, maybe file a bug of "missing migration guide" ?

Comment: the answer is [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1783)

Comment: short answer : use `instance_options` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using instance_options, your serializer should look like this:

```
class Api::V1::SerializerWithSessionMetadata < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :app_rights
    def app_rights
        @instance_options[:app_rights]
    end
end
```

To ensure that the correct serializer gets called, you can render a specific serializer like this (otherwise it will render whatever is defined for the class on @dia):

```
render json: @dia, serializer: SerializerWithSessionMetadata, app_rights: app_rights(@dia)
```

Comment: Thanks, by specifying the serializer it works (it turns out I now need to specify the serializer everywhere throughout the app, not just for the above example). This is really strange and if possible I would like to find out why this is.

This is what I found out: with the new gem version, if I don't specify the serializer in the controller, it still automatically uses the RIGHT serializer but it does not serialize the attributes that are calculated inside a method in the serializer. In other words, it only serializes attributes it can directly read from the database. Any ideas about this?

Comment: If AMS doesn't find the right serializer, it just turns the object to json, which will only read the DB attributes. AMS will automatically link the correct serializer only if you name your serializer class MyObjectSerializer, if @dia is a MyObject.